# Graphics are slower in 11.10 after upgrade

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, nvidia

I just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10 and i noticed that graphics are slower. I had the nvidia driver downloaded from their website in 11.04. After the upgrade the pc wouldn't actually boot in kernel 3.0, so i went to 2.x.38 and installed the nvidia driver from the repos. After this change, 3.0 was working but, as i said, with some regressions.OpenArena, for example, was slower.  Plus, I noticed in Openarena tearing and in FF too. It may be a system wide thing though, i don't know.

So my question is ... how can i verify if the driver is installed correct?

But if i understood the problem incorrect, please help me out identifying it!

Comment: Installing from nvidia.com is a bad idea since it's not compatible with the system and breaks some libraries. For the list of files being modified, see https://lists.launchpad.net/bumblebee/msg00019.html

Comment: run *nvidia-settings* in terminal to find out if it is installed correctly. To install: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers/66335#66335

Comment: @Lekensteyn, thx, but that list overwhelms me. And i don't think i can run the same steps since relatively a lot of time has passed since my install.

Comment: @Trevor, nvidia-setting works.

Comment: Do you have the latest driver installed?

Comment: yes. nvidia-current. v280

Answer (score 1):

this happened to me also, in 11.04 my graphics were fine but as soon as i fresh installed 11.10 it was slow, i have a system76 weldebeest with a gt430 card and on 11.04 nothing could stop it but in 11.10 i can barely do anything without lag its horrible and makes me sad...  i have drivers installed from the drivers applet, and i found a ppa that if you use to upgrade it helps the performance a tiny bit but this thing is still laggy as hell.

this is the ppa i used 
http://blog.al4.co.nz/2011/10/slow-desktop-performance-on-ubuntu-11-10-with-nvidia-graphics-cards/

like i said this helps a little but performance sucks horribly in 11.10

Comment: Nice to know i'm not alone. I can also say that with the latest xorg update openarena seems to be a little bit faster, but still not as in 11.04.

Comment: Yea I mostly play Minecraft and World of Tanks. Back in 11.04 nothing could stop my computers, now it can barely play minecraft... Oneric sucks for performance.