# Display resolution with NVIDIA

Tags: nvidia, resolution

I'm using a Leadtek Winfast A340 AGP 8X graphics card (NVIDIA Geforce fx 5200) and a monitor that has a resolution of 1280x1024.  Without installing additional drivers the available display resolutions are 1024x768 and 800x600.  If I activate an NVIDIA accelerated graphics driver, e.g. version 173 which was listed as recommended, only 640x480 is available.

Is there any way of activating, my using an alternative driver or other means, a 1280x1024 resolution option which matches the monitor?  I've only been dabbling in Ubuntu this last week so an answer suitable for a novice would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest drivers for your system by downloading it from nvidia.com and installing it using the posted procedure [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers) and see if that helps.

Comment: I managed to sort this out.  After installing the NVIDIA driver version 173 via the GUI, I opened a terminal added my desired resolution using nvidia-xconfig: sudo nvidia-xconfig --mode=1280x1024.  This generated a valid version of xorg.conf.  I also manually edited xorg.conf to set the correct HorizSync and VertRefresh for my monitor.