# Can't install nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, cuda

Today I tried to install the Nvidia drivers on my 11.10 ubuntu. 
I done everything what told on http://www.dickscheid.net/2011/10/19-cuda-ubuntu-1110/ and http://blog.ryant.org/2011/12/installing-cuda-toolkit-on-ubuntu-1110.html
then i reboot
now i see only title "Ubuntu" and ~5 points
I cant even switch to console (ctrl alt f 1-6)
anybody know what i can to do to save my ubuntu?

Comment: Now i undestand, that can switch to console using recovery mode! but i dont know how uninstall drivers.. or cure ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

[How do I install the latest NVIDIA drivers from the .run file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers)

here I got a very good answer on how to install latest drivers. Works like a charm.