# Drivers corrupted after update for first time?

Tags: 12.10, boot, drivers, dual-boot, fan

I had dual booted Ubuntu 12.10 with Windows 7 on my Laptop.
After installing I observed that the fan was on all the time, resulting in huge electricity usage.
There was an alert that I had ~200 updates. So I installed them.
When I restarted my Laptop, there ws GRUB. But when booted Ubuntu, it stayed blank & could not load Ubuntu.
So I again restarted my Laptop & booted something like "Ubuntu safe mode" which was showed on GRUB. So it started showing all the drivers that were loading. And suddenly it hanged at a spot. It didnt show any error or such thing. But I think the drivers got corrupted.

1. Why was the fan always the first time, even though I had not installed any updates or anything?
2. So, why might have this (drivers getting corrupted after update) happened?
3. Is there a way to repair Ubuntu or do I have to re-install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Fan always on

   - Could be several reasons. Most probable you have a dual graphics card Like nvdia `optimus` or ATI hybrid switchable graphics card. Without installing correct graphics card driver, both GPU always turned on and heat up very quickly. So the fans always run to keep them cool.
2. The second one because of same issue. The graphics card.
3. Yes, hopefully you can.

   - Use `nomodeset` kernel parameter to get past black screen as instructed in  First answer of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)
   - If you can not get past black screen try booting older kernel (located under `Ubuntu Advanced` menu item in grub) or try https://askubuntu.com/a/162078
   - If you get past black screen , follow the guides according to your graphics card

---

- **ATI**

  One ATI graphics card -

  [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

  ATI Hybrid card

  [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working)

**Nvidia**

- If you only have nvidia graphics card (**NON OPTIMUS**) then follow -

  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

  or

  [How do I install the latest NVIDIA drivers from the .run file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-by-hand)
- If optimus :
  [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Comment: Hi Web-E, Thanks a lot for your detailed reply.
For the 2nd point I have slightly updated the question.
I have ATI Radeon 7670m HD Grpahics Card & also Intel HD series graphics.

Comment: Since I was using the Open source drivers & it was having problems, should I move on to the proprietory drivers from ATI?
I am a bit sceptical on this one, because I read in some questions that there screen turns black/blue with the ATI Drivers.
What do you reckon I should do?
Thanks for your help again. :)

Comment: @Cool_Coder not very sure if using open source driver causes the issue. you check in `/etc/modprobe.d/` whether the readoen driver is blacklisted. Regarding your second question, I have never used an ATI card so I can't give you advices on that. But you can try once, anyway best way to keep one GPU off is to use the proprietary GPU.