# How to install Ubuntu 13.10 if hardware doesn't support nouveau video driver

Tags: drivers, 13.10, nvidia, xorg, nouveau

I have Acer Aspire V3-772G laptop with NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M.
I had a 13.04 with windows 8 until recently and all works fine. But when I try to install 13.10 from usb it crashes during boot. According to logs the reason is that **nouveau  driver** doesn't support my video card and therefore X server can't start.
**So how can I replace nouveau driver in ISO image with proprietary NVIDIA driver?**

I tried to download 331.20 NVIDIA driver (.run), set up `nomodeset` and when the error occurred, I took these steps:

1. Rename downloaded file `nvidia.run` (for convenience) and move it t my home directory
2. Install libraries for compiling things: `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-uname -r`
3. Reset xorg.conf to basic state: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg`
4. Turn off Display Manager: `sudo /etc/init.d/mdm stop`
5. Run nvidia installer: `sudo sh nvidia.run`
   (And the driver 331.20 - really installed (so I can see libglx.so.331.20 in /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions))
6. rename origin libglx.so to libglx.so.orig, and libglx.so.331.20 to libglx.so (make a link with `ln -s`)
7. `sudo /etc/init.d/mdm start`

and I still see the same. Error:
`"Failed to start X server...." and "(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration..."`

**Can anybody tell me how to correctly install ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop? Thanks for advance...**

P.S. Here is my log:

```
[    27.278] 
X.Org X Server 1.14.3
Release Date: 2013-09-12
[    27.278] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    27.278] Build Operating System: Linux 3.2.0-37-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    27.278] Current Operating System: Linux mint 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64
[    27.278] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/linuxmint.seed boot=casper iso-scan/filename= quiet splash -- nomodeset
[    27.278] Build Date: 15 October 2013  09:23:37AM
[    27.278] xorg-server 2:1.14.3-3ubuntu2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    27.278] Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
[    27.278]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    27.278] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    27.278] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Feb 22 18:31:05 2014
[    27.278] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    27.278] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    27.278] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    27.278] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    27.278] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    27.278] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    27.278] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    27.278] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    27.278] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    27.278] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    27.278]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.278] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    27.278]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.278] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    27.278]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.278] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    27.278]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.278] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    27.278]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    27.278] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    27.278] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    27.278] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    27.278] (II) Loader magic: 0x7f7d55074d20
[    27.278] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    27.278]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    27.278]    X.Org Video Driver: 14.1
[    27.278]    X.Org XInput driver : 19.1
[    27.278]    X.Org Server Extension : 7.0
[    27.279] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:0416:1025:0781 rev 6, Mem @ 0xd3000000/4194304, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64
[    27.279] (--) PCI: (0:1:0:0) 10de:0fe4:1025:0781 rev 161, Mem @ 0xd2000000/16777216, 0xa0000000/268435456, 0xb0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    27.279] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension RECORD
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension DPMS
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XVideo
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension SELinux
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DGA
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension XFree86-DRI
[    27.279] Initializing built-in extension DRI2
[    27.279] (II) "glx" will be loaded by default.
[    27.279] (WW) "xmir" is not to be loaded by default. Skipping.
[    27.279] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    27.279] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    27.279] (II) LoadModule: "glamoregl"
[    27.279] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglamoregl.so
[    27.280] (II) Module glamoregl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.280]    compiled for 1.14.2.901, module version = 0.5.1
[    27.280]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    27.280] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    27.280] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    27.280] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.280]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.280]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 7.0
[    27.280] (==) AIGLX enabled
[    27.280] Loading extension GLX
[    27.280] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
[    27.280] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 1
[    27.280] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 2
[    27.280] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 3
[    27.280] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[    27.280] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    27.280] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    27.280] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.280]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 2.99.904
[    27.280]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    27.280]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    27.280] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[    27.280] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[    27.280] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.280]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 2.3.2
[    27.280]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    27.280]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    27.280] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[    27.281] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[    27.281] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.281]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.8.0
[    27.281]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    27.281]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    27.281] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[    27.281] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[    27.281] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.281]    compiled for 1.14.1, module version = 0.4.3
[    27.281]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    27.281]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    27.281] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43, HD Graphics,
    HD Graphics 2000, HD Graphics 3000, HD Graphics 2500,
    HD Graphics 4000, HD Graphics P4000, HD Graphics 4600,
    HD Graphics 5000, HD Graphics P4600/P4700, Iris(TM) Graphics 5100,
    HD Graphics 4400, HD Graphics 4200, Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200
[    27.281] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    27.281] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    27.281] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    27.281] (++) using VT number 8

[    27.286] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    27.286] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    27.286] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[    27.286] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[    27.286] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[    27.286] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[    27.286] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.286]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 0.0.2
[    27.286]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    27.286] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[    27.286] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[    27.286] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[    27.286] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.286]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.1.0
[    27.286]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    27.286] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[    27.286] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[    27.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[    27.287] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.287]    compiled for 1.14.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.287]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 14.1
[    27.287] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[    27.287] (EE) VESA(0): V_BIOS address 0x0 out of range
[    27.287] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[    27.287] (II) UnloadSubModule: "int10"
[    27.287] (II) Unloading int10
[    27.287] (II) UnloadSubModule: "vbe"
[    27.287] (II) Unloading vbe
[    27.287] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[    27.287] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[    27.287] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[    27.287] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[    27.287] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[    27.287] (EE) 
[    27.292] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: the driver you are trying to compile it's actually not the latest for your video card look here http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: I was trying with 331.49 driver, but result is the same

Comment: as I remember it's beta driver. And how are you installing where do you get stuck? What tutorial are you using?

Comment: no actually it's not beta my mistake :-)

Comment: follow my workaround in my answer (marked red) it does work

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-by-hand) there's also a workout provided by me.

to install without X GUI from Console:

```
jockey-text -l
jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current
```

or in the Graphical GUI:

Open Settings/Additional Drivers

to install proprietary driver in Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) or better tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

after proprietary driver installation's complete don't forget to configure X:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

and start Nvidia settings:

```
gksudo nvidia-settings
```

if you need or want to remove Nouveau and the rest of Nvidia currently installed on your system take a look at marked solution.

Comment: I can't do  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` cause i can't set up internet connection by wpa_supplicant. I shows `ioctl [SIOCSIWENCODEEXT] Invalid Argument` error

Comment: what do you mean you can't?

Comment: you need to make sure and tell whether you want to use proprietary driver or Nvidia latest?

Comment: I want to replace nouveau driver with nvidia, so i can go on with installation. For this purpose I download drivers and trying to install them during installation. I can't do it automaticaly because of wpa connection problems.

Comment: follow my tutorial in my answer marked solution

Comment: if you want completely delete nouveau and everything follow every step

Comment: Not work...Maybe "nomodeset" don't let the x server to be started...but to disable "nomodeset" I must reboot(I can't do that because I installing new OS from live usb)

Comment: I'm confused do you have Ubuntu installed already on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems as you, so I made myself a little paper note which I keep near my computer, and that note contains this:

- create new internet connection (only for wired connections)

> sudo pppoeconf

- follow on-screen instructions
- activate recently created internet connection

> pon dsl-provider

- add Nvidia ppa and install Nvidia drivers

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates 
>  sudo apt-get update 
>   sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings

- reboot your computer