# After Nvidia 331 and Bumblebee install, OpenGL reverts to old version

Tags: 14.04, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, opengl

I recently installed Bumblebee and the Nvidia 331 driver, because [apparently this was the only way to get my Geforce 860m to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477765/ubuntu-14-04-doesnt-detect-my-discrete-gpu).  Now, when I try to compile OpenGL programs, it behaves as if I have a pre-2.0 version of OpenGL ("error: glFoo was not declared in this scope" for shader-related functions like glUniform1f).  These errors occur when trying to compile programs that were able to compile before, using the same makefiles as before.

The only way I've found to get around this is to use GLEW, which is unfortunate because I am a T.A. for an OpenGL class and need to be able to run students' assignments on my machine, and their assignments will not be using GLEW.

GLxinfo tells me that I have OpenGL version 3.0, but the only programs that will compile are ones that are written for pre-2.0.

Did Bumblebee/Nvidia replace one of my OpenGL libraries with an older version or something? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shouldn't have installed linux-headers-generic. I've edited the answer to my other question to reflect this.