# Ubuntu 12.04 - incorrect graphics information

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am checking my system settings, but see Graphics as unknown. I have Nvidia graphics card.

I tried this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/85322/26672), and ran :

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Now if I check it, instead of showing my Nvidia information, it shows :

[image]

How can I make sure my Nvidia card is configured properly and shown in system settings ?

**Edit**

Current nvidia installations :

```
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
nvidia-304-updates              install
nvidia-current-updates          install
nvidia-settings                 install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have not installed Nvdia Drivers in your system,

```
$ sudo nvdia -v
```

Will show your driver version[if installed and configured correctly].

To check Nvdia configuration, follow this [link](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/alt-nvidia-current-settings.1.html).

If you not yet installed Nvdia Drivers, follow this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).

Alternatively you can install manually at your own risk described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual).

Comment: Please see edit regarding what is currently installed.

Comment: `sudo nvidia -v` returns : `sudo nvidia -v
sudo: nvidia: command not found
`

Comment: @Jake click here to download drivers https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331_331.79.orig.tar.gz and install it in your system... then try the same and tell me..

Comment: Should I try to follow the additional driver installation way ?

Comment: The tar has 2 files. I am using 64 bit. Run both (only 1 seems to labeled for 64 bit) ? Thanks.

Comment: @Jake install 64-bit

Comment: OK I'll run `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-331.79-no-compat32.run` (I had to make it executable)

Comment: It says : You appear to be running X-server. Please close it before installation.

Comment: @Jake http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file ; this may help you...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15772/discussion-between-a-j-and-jake).

Comment: Please see this : http://askubuntu.com/q/498636/26672