# Ubuntu 12.04 - problem with nvidia drivers

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, resolution

I installed 12.04 LTS recently. I installed Nvidia drivers running the following in the terminal :

```
$ sudo apt-get purge nvidia-* 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

I also tried installing via the RUN file : [link](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331_331.79.orig.tar.gz).

After executing the RUN file and rebooting, my screen resolution is stuck at 640 X 480. I have a FHD screen.

I have run `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` again, and now want to ask how can I ask fix this problem. Right now I have nothing relevant to Nvidia on my system.

Running `sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia` gives me an empty result.

My screen resolution is still 640 X 480.

(there are so many answers out there on this topic and commands in various order, that I had to ask it again, sorry if its exactly a duplicate)

**Edit**

I tried uninstalling using the run file, and it asked me if I want to bring back the backedup x settings. I clicked yes. After uninstall & reboot, the desktop just had a wallpaper.

Then I ran :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates
```

I rebooted again. Right now desktop looks normal.

If I run

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
```

I get

```
nvidia-304-updates              install
nvidia-current-updates          install
nvidia-settings                 install
```

My system settings still shows `Graphics : unknown`.

How do I tell if my display drivers are configured correctly ?

I can also run :

```
 $ nvidia-settings
```

and a window titled `Nvidia X Server Settings` pops up. Does this mean everything is ok , despite settings telling me `unknown graphics` ?

**Edit 2**

I tried installing `mesa-utils`, now instead of showing unknown graphics, it shows it as blank :P .. is that better ?

[image]

**Edit 3**

I think my nvidia driver is still no configured properly. Referring this [answer](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/233462)

When I run :

```
glxinfo | grep vendor
```

I get

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

Expected output :

```
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
```

What to do ?

**Edit 4**

I also tried

```
$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GK208M [GeForce GT 730M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff 
   memory:d0000000-   d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
   *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:49 memory:f1000000-f13fffff memory:e0000000
   -efffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
   WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run 
   this program as super-user.
```

Does this indicate everything is in order ?

**Edit 5**

Here's my additional driver window :

[image]

Should I go ahead & enable 304 ?

**Edit 6**

After running

```
 sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

as per one of the suggestions, the additional driver windows changed to :

[image]

Also :

```
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia
nvidia-304                  install
nvidia-304-updates          install
nvidia-current              install
nvidia-current-updates      install
nvidia-settings             install
```

Graphics settings is still blank.

Running `$nvidia-settings` shows me :

[image]

What is left to do ??

**Edit 7**

With no one replying ... I am installing the last entry in the list, and deactivating 304. Now I will try `sudo nvidia-xconfig` & a reboot. fingers crossed ..

[image]

Comment: To see the current driver run `lshw -c video`

Comment: @user107425 please see edit.

Comment: @user107425 I edited with the command you suggested.

Comment: Your running the Intel video driver. `configuration: driver=i915`

Comment: @user107425 Please look at the edit I just made.

Comment: @user107425 Do you think activating 304 would solve it ?

Comment: Try  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Comment: I already did : `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`. are you sure ?

Comment: the 304 is for older cards, the 7 series cards need the most updated driver.

Comment: I have GeForce GT 730M. Ok let me try running it. hold on ..

Comment: @user107425 please check edit.

Comment: @user107425 I also put the dpkg output.

Comment: @user107425 what would you suggest based on the edits ?

Comment: @Jake shall you tell me when you brought your laptop ?

Comment: @AJ This is brand new machine. Only 1 month old. Its a thinkpad t440p.

Comment: @AJ Right now to make Genymotion work, I have removed all nvidia drivers because I can't find a solution.

Comment: @Jake then you should need Nvidia help, try my answer...

Comment: @Jake I hope so this will help you.... http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-amd64-display-archive.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15796/discussion-between-a-j-and-jake).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but think so Ubuntu not providing Nvidia latest driver version directly. You need to get help from Nvidia.

I think you need latest driver version, remove 331 that already installed, you can get Nvidia various driver version. Latest released on July 10, 2014.

Click [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-amd64-display-archive.html).

Answer (score 1):

You will need [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) to enable the nvidia gpu.

For 12.04

`sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`

`sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop linux-headers-generic-lts-raring`

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable`

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`

`reboot`

check these settings against your installed driver and adjust as necessary

`sudo nano /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf`

*If you update the driver you will have to edit this file and adjust the settings.

`Driver=nvidia`

`KernelDriver=nvidia-331-updates`

`LibraryPath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331-updates`

`XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/nvidia-331-updates/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules`

Usage [command] [option] [program]

`optirun -b primus glxspheres`

Or

`primusrun` `glxgears`

`primusrun` `firefox`

`primusrun` `wine gta-vc.exe`

`primusrun` `steam`

`primusrun` `nvidia-settings`