# nvidia 840m driver problem with kubuntu 14.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu

I'm having some trouble installing the 346 driver on Kubuntu 14.10. After I followed this [tutorial](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-the-nvidia-346-47-driver-on-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivative-systems/) and after I reboot the system (without anything saying that I must do that after installation), It gives me a black screen in the moment I have to write the password and login. Although I did wrote the password, pressed return and started, but another problem was with the DSL connection.

It wasn't working any more so please can I get some help? I'm a beginner in linux and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: so you have a problem with a black screen (display) or dsl connection?

Comment: What i`m trying to say is that after the driver installation , my  system does not work properly and problems like the black screen and dsl connection started and after i uninstalled the 346 driver everything came to normal . Is there another way to install this driver correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xorg-edgers not always guarantee what you expect. You might have to remove it. Do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository remove ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

or with ppa-purge (it has to be installed)

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

if you can't get to desktop or tty terminal see the link below how to drop to root shell.

And after that other solution is Bumblebee:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

more detailed on Bumblebee [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee)

or use manual installation guide with detailed explanation:

[How to install nvidia driver manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619)

[How to drop to root shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help , this really helped me !