# How to install NVIDIA drivers to PowerMac G5

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, powerpc

I don't know how to install much-needed nvidia drivers on my powermac g5 quad. I am using ubuntu 14.04.2. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I cannot get into desktop

Comment: Which nvidia adapter is there? What `lspci | grep VGA` shows?

Comment: How did you install the system? Did it work from LiveCD?

Comment: I used 12.04.5 install and it didn't work there either and I upgraded and now I can't get to desktop

Comment: I can now get to the login but it won't actually login it just rests after I hit enter and goes back to login screen

Comment: Try to run also `rm .Xauthority .ICEauthority` in tty.

Comment: Ok tried that and it still won't let me log in

Comment: What driver is installed now?

Comment: Not sure... how do I check? I tried the lspci thing and it gave back geforce 6600

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25635/discussion-between-pilot6-and-nerd7473).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: I got Geforce 6600 on my older computer :D just use nvidia driver 304.125 it works fine it shipped by default with Ubuntu though I downloaded it from Nvidia website you can use [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers) tutorial or manually install it using [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619) tutorial.

Comment: You were right in the chat going to xubuntu

Comment: @JoKeR It is for powerpc platform, not i386 or amd64.

Comment: @Pilot6 I see I was confused ;) but still as I just checked Nvidia has driver support for Linux 32/64bit i386/amd64/EMT in driver 304.125 and Quadro FX4500 is listed there)

Comment: @JoKeR With that old adapters this Nvidia list is wrong. They are very badly supported in fact. Practically unusable in many cases.

Comment: @Pilot6 probably you're right this is old school adapters :D though runs fine on my older PC using Geforce 6600 ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no proprietary Nvidia drivers supporting this adapter for powerpc platform. And it looks like nouveau does not support 3D acceleration well for it.

The only solution I see is to install Xubuntu. It does not require 3D acceleration and it may work with open source drivers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-311-updates
```

and it might work.

Comment: It might NOT work, because there is no such package.

Comment: There is still no package `nvidia-311-updates`

Comment: Please do not suggest solutions that you are not sure of or do not know how to use. At least try to run commands you are suggesting.

Comment: I am sure about this one, they work once on my computer, and updates comes all the time.

Comment: @Michael you might be mistaken or confused on *Quadro/Tesla* that what this driver is that you have recommended for... but he uses GPU on Geforce 6600 which is way and way older...