# Nvidia 760 GTX 14.04 Driver Install Problem

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hdmi

I know there are lot of posts with similar titles... but I think I've tried about all of them.

I can't seem to get nvidia drivers to work.

Failure mode.
I go through the below steps... After rebooting... the system will seem to boot normally (even a glimpse of the ubuntu splash page).. but eventually... all output from my HDMI will cease.. and my TV will just say "no signal from HDMI"

System

Nvidia 760GTX
Samsung 46" TV as Monitor
 Connected Via HDMI from video card to monitor.

Steps.

```
1. Clean install of ubuntu 14.04
2. apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
3. add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
4. apt-get update
```

from here it diverges..  first I tried

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

and I would get the failure mode described above.

All subsequent attempts... I instead would do a...

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
```

For this last step.. I started with the the 'recommended' driver listed here (364).. and then I tried the one nvidia recommends for the 760GTX on their website (361)... and then I tried all the rest...

Same failure mode.

Any ideas?  I'm wondering if others might have some insight into the failure mode where the HDMI signal just seems to get lost.

Thanks!

Comment: you can read my article over [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file/423619#423619) to understand a little bit more about nvidia drivers... I've been using nvidia official driver on Ubuntu for all the years using hdmi and on different nvidia videocards and no issues whatsoever.

Comment: I will give using the official drivers from their website a try and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It seems difficult to figure out the issue from the problems you just described. Primarily, I suspect this could be nouveau issue. 
If you are installing Nvidia driver, then nouveau should be disabled.

One way you can do to disable nouveau is by adding nouveau.modeset=0 as kernel parameter :

`# grubby  --update-kernel=ALL  --args=nouveau.modeset=0`

and then reboot the system.

Comment: Isn't `grubby` only available to RPM-based distros? So [Fedora](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Configuring_GRUB_2_Using_the_grubby_Tool.html) and Red Hat, but not Ubuntu. CTRL+F "Ubuntu" [here](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/fedora-30-grub-persistent-changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

The GTX760 has a DVI-I output connector. Try connecting a DVI to VGA adaptor to it and then connect to a monitor using a VGA cable. If this works then you will be able to play with the different drivers. The article by JoKeR seems very comprehensive.

Comment: Hmm... but it also has HDMI (which is what I'm using while using the standard xorg drivers)... Are you thinking that the DVI -> VGA would work while the HDMI would not?

Comment: I think it is certainly worth a try since this is an analog output rather than digital.  I am using a much older Nvidea card (GeForce 8600) and I had problems using the xorg (nouveau) driver. In my case it would sometimes boot correctly and sometimes boot to a black screen. Changing to the recommended Nvidea driver has made it much more reliable.