# Unable to solve login loop problem after installing nvidia driver via run file

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

I know the likes of this question have been asked many times, but I couldn't find an answer that would work for me, so I'm asking a new one!

As the title suggests I encounter a login loop after installing nvidia driver via run file. I must say that for some reasons **I cannot use apt-get install nvidia-... so please don't suggest this**.

The problem started after an update and a reboot, where I was greeted with a black screen. As I have had experienced this before I tried to reinstall the driver but with no use.

I tried the steps suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/423619 , but this didn't solve it (only everything in the login page became very big!). I tried it with three different drivers (352.99, my previous one before this catastrophe, 361.77, 367.57). I have tried the steps suggested in https://vxlabs.com/2015/02/05/solving-the-ubuntu-14-04-nvidia-346-nvidia-prime-black-screen-issue/ which has worked on my other laptop before, but again no use.

I added the line:
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.blacklist=1"
to /etc/default/grub and then ran sudo update-grub, but still no use.

The thing is I really need nvidia driver for my work and I can't replace it with other choices, also I really don't want to reinstall my ubuntu because then I have to reinstall so many things I had in it. I'm using an HP laptop with a 850M gpu on it and Ubuntu 14.04.3.

I've been searching for two days trying everything but nothing works! Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

I would also appreciate any hints as how to avoid such a problem in future, meaning to have my nvidia driver, update my system and yet don't get stuck with things like login loop, black screen etc.

Comment: *"for some reasons I cannot use `apt-get install nvidia-`"* - Could you please elaborate?

Comment: AFIK if you insist on using the "run" file you should look to nvidia for support as it is a closed source driver. There are reasons, as you can see, why you should use the ubuntu repositories to install the nvidia driver ;)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen , I know it's better to use ubuntu repositories but I have installed driver via run file before and it worked, I don't know what's wrong this time... and besides you cannot use the latest driver when using repositories, which in my case matters because of the speed up and other features it offers.

Comment: It is a closed source driver , so ... https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/522835/linux/if-you-have-a-problem-please-read-this-first/