# My monitor is blurry when I downloaded updates

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, display-resolution, monitor

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, I've got a Nvidia GT 730. My screen is all blurry but if I click somewhere ie the desktop it will be clear for a bit around that area and then reblur.

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

Returns

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. GF108 [GeForce GT 730]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

I'm a bit new to Ubuntu. I don't know any more info to give, so please tell me what to include.

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Yes, it was working fine till I installed new updates.

Comment: How did you install those drivers?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: That may be some hardware problem (cable, etc). It is unlikely a software issue.

Comment: Where should I look for the hardware problem? And is there a chance it is in fact a software issue?

Comment: Which Nvidia driver is installed? how did you install it?

Comment: I'm using 367.57, I installed using the .run file. I believe I used this http://askubuntu.com/questions/66328/how-do-i-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-from-the-run-file.

Comment: It is wrong to install using a run file. Uninstall it using the run file and install by `sudo apt install nvidia-367`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is wrong with your setting specific to one user, since the guest account is OK.

The easiest way to solve this is to create a new account and transfer your files there.

But do not copy all hidden config files, because one or a few of those contain the problematic setting.

Comment: It said it's up to date though.

Comment: Also I've done that, and restarted the computer and it's still blurry. (It's fine until after I login.)

Comment: OK, then try to login as guest. If there is no problem with the guest account, it means that something is wrong with your user account.

Comment: Guest is clear, but my user account has the problem.

Comment: You can create a new user account and move all your files there. That will fix the issue. So the problem is not with drivers, but with your user settings.

Comment: I will edit the answer since it is wrong.